# Calculating rotated relative positions on 2D plane

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, 2d

For a game project, I need to calculate positions of items on a 2D plane relative to the camera.

Camera can be rotated, and it's coordinates refer to it's center.

[image: image01]
[image: image02]

In the attached images, `a` and `b` are items to display and `c` is camera.
First image is absolute positions of items in the world.
Second image is the result I'm trying to get.

Please note that rotation doesn't have to be 90 degrees, it can be any valid angle. I just used 90 degrees to keep this example simple.

Normally this is an easy task, but because camera can be rotated, translating to/from the center is not that easy, and it makes this problem complicated.

This is not using canvas element, so using canvas translation or rotation is not an option.

Here is the data used in this example, and some boilerplate code for trying solutions:

```
var items = {
    a: {x: 3, y: 3},
    b: {x: 2, y: 4}
};

var camera = {
    x: 4, y: 4,
    width: 4, height: 4,
    rotation: 90
}
```

[boilerplate code on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/jtdpvdr7/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please replace your image with larger one, It is very hard to read its content

Comment: What does camera's width and height mean? Is it perspective? I can't understand your problem!

Comment: Images are replaced with enlarged ones.

Comment: Width and height of the camera is important for final positions. In the final image, A is (1,3). But (1,3) from where? Top left corner of the view, which is calculated by subtracting width/2 and height/2 from camera center (when it's not rotated). Sounds easy, but when the camera can be rotated 37 degrees, it's difficult.

Comment: Isn't better to ask your question on [Math site on Stack Exchange network](http://www.math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Maybe, I'll try there as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should do these steps to achieve your result

1. [Translate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29) the origin to the `C` point
2. Rotate your points by [Rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)
3. Return back the origin to its original position

At this point, your items and camera has been rotated, the only work that still is left, is the clipping by camera rectangle.

As far as I know such a clipping is not very hard and can be done easily.

Hope it helps you

Comment: You're correct, these are the steps, and I have no problem with first 2. But, for the third one, you need to go to the top-left corner of camera rectangle. But, because we have rotated it, it's not as easy as subtracting width/2 and height/2. Those distance vectors should be rotated too. This is where I fail.

Comment: @jsnoob As I saw your image, your relative origin does not rotate and still remains in top-left, in the other side your transformed items is positioned relative to the origin (in the top-left), so clipping can be done by some sum and subtract, not?

Comment: Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/vyLtqwg2/1/

I have added all 3 steps.
(it could be done shortly in the same `for`, but this is easier for debugging).

Can you please look at this 3rd phase? (Remember that it needs to work for other angles too, so using 90degrees rotation shortcuts is not an option.)